# Lipschitz continuity and continuously differentiable functions

Tags: continuity

I have to prove that a certain function $F(x): \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuously differentiable and its Jacobian $J(x)$ is Lipschitz continuous.

Are both criteria fulfilled if

$ \left\Vert J(y) - J(x) \right\Vert \leq L \left\Vert y- x \right\Vert \quad \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^m$

is fulfilled? And what does the Lipschitz continuity of the Jacobian tell me about the Lipschitz continuity of the function $F(x)$ itself?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you prove that the Jacobian function $J:\mathbb{R}^m\to {\cal L}(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^n)$ is Lipschitz continuous, then you've also proven that it's continuous. (Lipchitz continuity $\implies$ continuity!) To say $F:\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is **differentiable** is to say that the map $J:\mathbb{R}^m\to {\cal L}(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^n)$ is **well-defined**. To say that $F$ is **continuously differentiable** is to say that the map $J$ is **not only well-defined but also continuous**. So, yes, if you prove that $J$ is Lipschitz continuous, then you've proven something stronger than is required to prove that $F$ is continuously differentiable.

The function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by the rule $f(x)=x^2$ has Lipchitz continuous derivative $f':\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ (defined by the rule $f'(x)=2x$) but is not itself Lipschitz continuous.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just to be sure: Lipschitz continuity of the Jacobian implies continuous differentiability of $F(x)$ ? And what does it tell me about the Lipschitz continuity of $F(x)$ ?

Comment: Hi @bonanza (I know that sounds ...), no I don't think so, unfortunately. I've given a counterexample in my answer. Let me know if you'd like help with anything else!

Comment: $f(x) = x^2$ is not Lipschitz continuous (because it's derivative is unbounded) but it's derivative $f^\prime(x) = 2x$ is Lipschitz continuous because it's derivative $f^{\prime \prime} = 2$ is bounded - correct?